# MySQL Insert Foreign key Multiple tables using ID

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys

I have two tables, one that has simple 'client' data, and the other that has a 'state' of the client.  I have a foreign key for the ID in both tables.

Table A:
Id (int) PK AI
ClientId (bigint) UN PK
LastContact (datetime)

Table B:
Id (int) PK Foreign key to Table A Id
Other columns....

When I insert/update in to my 'client' table, I am relying on the ClientId, not the table Id, like so.

```
INSERT INTO client (ClientId, ClientType, LastContact) Values (Client_Id, Client_Type, Last_Contact) ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE ClientType=Client_Type, LastContact=Last_Contact;
```

How do I know the ID I have inserted, or updated, to then be able to insert/update my second table.  I thought linking with a foreign key would make this easier, but I just can't seem to find a way.  Also, I was told using the ClientId for my Id is not a good idea because it is such a big number and will slow things down as the table grows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a snippet in the mysql manual that covers your exact situation.

> If a table contains an AUTO_INCREMENT column and INSERT ... UPDATE
>   inserts a row, the LAST_INSERT_ID() function returns the
>   AUTO_INCREMENT value. If the statement updates a row instead,
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() is not meaningful. However, you can work around this
>   by using LAST_INSERT_ID(expr). Suppose that id is the AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column. To make LAST_INSERT_ID() meaningful for updates, insert rows
>   as follows:
>
> INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;

So in your case, you would just amend your query to:

```
INSERT INTO client (ClientId, ClientType, LastContact) Values 
(Client_Id, Client_Type, Last_Contact) ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE ClientType=Client_Type, LastContact=Last_Contact, 
ClientId = LAST_INSERT_ID(ClientId);
```

You can then get the ID of the row which was added/updated with LAST_INSERT_ID(), or whatever function in the client library you're using.

Comment: OK, well that answers how I get the ID from either an INSERT, or an UPDATE, but how would I then use the LAST_INSERT_ID to insert/update my second table?  I just call the LAST_INSERT_ID to retrieve the ID, then do my next INSERT/UPDATE?  Or can I combine the INSERT/UPDATE in to one query?  I hope I am making sense.

Comment: If you don't need the ID for anything else, you should be able to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` directly in your next query.  Otherwise, you might want to query it separately to have it for later reference.

Comment: I just tried to use that method, but I don't get how the LAST_INSERT_ID knows the ID I am looking for.  So If I do: INSERT INTO client (ClientId, ClientType, LastContact) Values 
(123, 5, null) ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE ClientType=8, LastContact=null;

INSERT INTO clientstatus (Id, field1, field2) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(123), 55, 34) - How does it know to look in ClientID for the LAST_INSERT_ID?

Comment: OK, I get you now!  I figured it out.  Just a little difference to make it work.  I had to do this:  INSERT INTO client (ClientId, ClientType, LastContact) Values 
(666, 10, null) ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE ClientType=10, LastContact=null, Id = LAST_INSERT_ID(Id);

INSERT INTO clientstatus (Id, field1, field2) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 555, 34)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE field1= 555, field2 = 24;